# React. TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

this is my first question, i'm a newbie dev and i've been working on my first web app for a week. I'm stuck because i'm trying to make a simple mobile e commerce, i've made 8 cards and i've put a plus icon that needs to add the item in the cart when it is clicked, also it has to flip and become a cart icon.

I guess i can't access what it is inside the map method?! and i get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. The problem is inside the some method, I can't come up with any different solution. Any suggestion? Can you help me please? Thanks.

```
function Mobile() {
const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false)
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])

const mobiles = data.map(mobile => (
    <div className='card' key={mobile.id}
         onMouseEnter = {() => setHovered(true)}
         onMouseLeave = {() => setHovered(false)}

    >
            {cartIcon()}
            <img src= {mobile.img}  alt='Mobile phones' className='mobile-img' />
            <h3 className='mobile-title'>{mobile.title}</h3>
            <p className='mobile-info'>{mobile.info}</p>
            <p className='mobile-price'>€ {mobile.price}</p>
    </div>

))

function addToCart(newItem) {
setCartItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem])
```

}

```
function cartIcon() {
const alreadyInCart = cartItems.some(item => item ===  item.id)
if(alreadyInCart) {
    return <i className="ri-shopping-cart-fill cart"></i>
} else if(hovered) {
    return <i className="ri-add-circle-line cart" onClick = {() => addToCart()}></i>
}
```

}

Comment: Where does `data` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function declaration for adding to cart: `function addToCart(newItem)` expects the item to be passed in as an argument. However, you are passing it nothing:

```js
<i className="ri-add-circle-line cart" onClick = {() => addToCart()}></i>
```

So when it attempts to add the item to the cart here:

```js
setCartItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem])
```

`newItem` is undefined.

Then you attempt to access the property `id` of `undefined` and ... error.

```js
cartItems.some(item => item ===  item.id) // <- item is not an object
```

Pass in the `item` you want to add and it will solve your issue. You will have to add it both to the `cartIcon` call, and its definition, and then pass it to the `addToCart` after that.

The final result will include something like the following:

```js
{cartIcon(mobile)} // Pass the item

...

function cartIcon(item) { // Expect the item

...

// Add the item
return <i className="ri-add-circle-line cart" onClick = {() => addToCart(item)}></i>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i skipped the most important steps! I've been trying  for hours the solution and i can see the plus icon but when i click it nothing change. The some method for checking if there are items already in cart is not working as espected. I don't know what else i can do and why it's not working!

Comment: Ok, i'm very happy because i've made it! So, the some method didn't work, i used include: const alreadyInCart = cartItems.includes(item). It worked perfectly. Also i made a removeFromCart function and it works. I took several hours but i did it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass item to the cartIcon function. The error is because your function does not have access to whatever item is. I'm assuming it's mobile?
Inside your map pass mobile

```
{cartIcon(mobile)}
```

In the cart icon function create an arg called item

```
function cartIcon(item) {
const alreadyInCart = cartItems.some(item => item ===  item.id)
if(alreadyInCart) {
    return <i className="ri-shopping-cart-fill cart"></i>
} else if(hovered) {
    return <i className="ri-add-circle-line cart" onClick = {() => addToCart()}></i>
}
```

I can't see all the code but this should fix your error.